# How to start the my meteor app on an android device?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I was testing the new Meteor build 0.9.2 which integrates Phonegap now. Everything is working fine so far. But I don't really understand how to start my app on my android device.
The manual states that you should specify `meteor run android-device -p <local IP>:<local port>` and that the server and the device should be connected to the same local network. I use the ip and port of the server here. But I get this error:

`ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.`

I'm not sure how I should link my device to the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how it worked for me: You have to connect your device via usb to your computer. Activate developer-tools and usb-debugging. Then run `meteor run android-device -p <local IP>:<local port>`. Local IP should be the ip your computer has in the network, usually something like this 192.168.1.xx. Port is by default 3000.
To start an app without usb requires installing it on the device, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you need enable USB Debugging Mode
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6FkhSeiYd8

Answer (score 0):

1. Check both mobile and computer is on same network/internet connection.
2. Enable USB Debugging.
3. Restarting computer and mobile device also helps.